# JWT encode error Expected 3 arguments. Found 2

Tags: php, codeigniter, jwt, codeigniter-4

I try to create a restful api with JWT in CI4, when I create token with code below :

```
$key = getenv('TOKEN_SECRET');
    $payload = array(
        "iat" => 1356999524,
        "nbf" => 1357000000,
        "uid" => $user['id'],
        "email" => $user['email']
    );

    $token = JWT::encode($payload, $key);
```

Why do I get the error:

> Expected 3 arguments. Found 2

Answer (score 5):

The third paramter should be the algorithm you are trying to use for encoding.
For Example, HS256 is one of the algorithms.

So in your example it will be :

```
$token = JWT::encode($payload, $key, 'HS256');
```

You can refer to the following link for reference:
https://packagist.org/packages/firebase/php-jwt

Comment: thank you for help. The token can created but when I try decode the token at https://jwt.io/ get error "Invalid Signature", please help ?

Comment: To validate the key depending on the method you are using. You have to paste secret phrase or private & public key.